# EEE PC 701 stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot, eee-pc

I have a Asus EEE PC 701 4G that won't go past the bios screen. The keyboard isn't working either so I can't access the bios. I've tried a live OS on USB but it fails to load. It gets stuck at this screen: 
[image: eee pc boot screen]

Any thoughts on why this is happening? And how to fix it?

**EDIT**
Unfortunately theres not light for the caps lock so I can't test this, but I have plugged in an external keyboard and still nothing. I have also tried to reinstall the BIOS, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you upgraded the RAM or the BIOS lately?

Comment: Yes to the ram. Although I was given it in this condition, I upgraded the ram as I thought it might have been faulty, and I've been pressing the reset buttons and things.

Comment: @hesse ^ sorry forgot to mention you in the comment.

Comment: Check to see if the capslock light still toggles when it sticks. That will tell you if the computer is stuck or completely frozen

Comment: @ChargerIIC Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a faulty bios... If it real is, you have to get rid of it... Or, try making a FAT16 (not FAT32!!!!) USB, download the last bios (i think is 1307, rename it to 701.ROM and put it as the single file on the FAT16 formatted USB. Power it on, holding "Alt" + "F2" keys together. It should do a reflash that will look like the one below: **[Asus EEE PC 701 Boot Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFNhF.jpg)**